# Combobox com paginação dando erro ao fazer reload.

Tags: extjs

Tenho um combobox com paginação de pageSize: 20.
E tenho um checkbox que serve para filtrar alguns registros do combobox.
O erro ocorre quando antes de marchar o checkbox eu navego entre as paginas do combobox, e ao fazer o reload ele envia para minha controller.cs o parametro start: 20, porem quando eu faço o filtro ele não tem 20 registros dai fica sem informação.
Gostaria de saber como e onde eu consigo setar essa propriedade start: 0 ao fazer o reload da store que preenche o combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido, ao fazer o load na store responsável por preencher o combobox eu apenas mudei a função de 
store.load(); 
para store.loadPage(1);